# Grails 3.0.9 gradle new task with custom environment

Tags: grails, gradle, grails-3.0.9

I'm trying to create a new task in build.gradle for running "check" with a custom environment called "integration".

I've tried several things and I've been able to run the check task from my custom task but I can't find the way to set the environment in int.

This is the task that I have right now in build.gradle. The comments are for things that I've tried but all fail because the property doesn't exist.
I've also tried setting the task as type:GrailsTask, but with no luck

```
task integrationCheck(){
    dependsOn "check"
    //env = "integration"
    //grailsEnv = "integration"
    //tasks.check.env = "integration"
    //check.env = "integration"
    //project.property("grailsEnv")
}
```

**Edit: per @vinay-prajapati suggestion**

Have tried with this:

```
task integrationCheck << {
    systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'integration'
}
```

And it gives this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':integrationCheck'.
> Could not find method systemProperty() for arguments [spring.profiles.active, integration] on root project 'my-project'
```

Comment: task integrationCheck << {
   systemProperty 'spring.profiles.active', 'production'
}. Please try this.

Comment: have tried but gives an error